# How to properly (deep) map complex objects with C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a database with owner and vehicle tables with a one-to-many relationship. I want to get all vehicle details and map each owner to each vehicle but I must map the query to a BDO. Not sure on the LINQ syntax but I have the code below.

```
using (var databaseContext = new DBConnection()) {
   var vehicles = (from Vehicle in databaseContext.Vehicles
                         select Vehicle);

   return vehicles.Select(x => new VehicleBDO() {
      Id = x.Id,
      // ... more simple data types
      Owner = new OwnerBDO(
         x.Owner.Id,
         x.Owner.Name)
   }).ToList();
}
```

Creating a new ownerBDO as shown is giving me a `MethodNotSupportedException` with details:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities

I'm used to Java and new to LINQ so have no idea how to do it properly, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do the same thing you are doing with `VehicleBDO`: use a parameterless constructor and property setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wants you to do something like this:

```
Owner = new OwnerBDO() { Id = x.Owner.Id, name = x.Owner.Name},
```

(I don't know the property names for OwnerBDO so I guessed.)

Comment: So you don't need parentheses with object initializer.

Comment: The awful shame when you realise how obvious the answer was. Thank you very much. Credits to Jon too.

Comment: @GaryM if you have read the error message carefully you will what to do and what to search on Google => "Object initializer", "parameterless" c#

Comment: @GaryM Your shame made me upvote your question and comments :). Enjoy your shame :).

Comment: @GaryM - That's what I'm here for... shame and loathing.  :) Good luck.